# Log in to Facebook with phantomjs - 302 issues?

Tags: redirect, phantomjs, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to write a phantomjs script to log in to my facebook account and take a screenshot.

Here's my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var stepIndex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;

email = system.args[1];
password = system.args[2];

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

var steps = [
  function() {
    page.open("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(status) {
      page.evaluate(function(email, password) {
            document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = email;
            document.querySelector("input[name='pass']").value = password;

            document.querySelector("#login_form").submit();

            console.log("Login submitted!");
      }, email, password);
      page.render('output.png');
    });
  },
  function() {
    console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
  },
  function() {
    phantom.exit();
  }
]

setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[stepIndex] == "function") {
    console.log("step " + (stepIndex + 1));
    steps[stepIndex]();
    stepIndex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[stepIndex] != "function") {
    console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 10000);
```

(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256079/1040915), but note that I've upped the interval to 10s)

Called like so:

```
./phantomjs test.js <email> <password>
```

With output (filtering out the selfxss warnings from Facebook):

```
step 1
load started
load finished
Login submitted!
load started
load finished
step 2
<head></head><body></body>
step 3
test
complete!
```

(Note that the html output in step two is empty)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058889/1040915) suggests that there are problems with phantomjs' SSL options, but running with `--ssl-protocol=any` has no effect.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887888/casperjs-phantomjs-unable-to-open-facebook) appears to be a similar problem, but for caspar, not phantomjs (and on Windows, not Mac) - I've tried using `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes`, but that also had no effect.

I guessed that this might be a redirection problem (and, indeed, when I replicate this on Chrome, the response from clicking "Submit" was a `302 Found` with location `https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/?next`), but according to [this](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-navigation-requested.html) documentation I can set a `page.onNavigationRequested` handler - when I do so in my script, it doesn't get called.

I *think* [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389) issue is related, but it looks as if there's no fix there.

Comment: You can't tell whether it works or not with this script. Wrap `document.documentElement.innerHTML` in `page.evaluate(function(){return document.documentElement.innerHTML;})`.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks! Can you explain why page.evaluate(...) is necessary to enact the redirect? I would have expected it to be carried out automatically.

Comment: The redirect works fine. It's just that `document` has no meaning outside of the page context.