# CasperJS Login to Facebook

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

After trying this answer 
[How to login into a website with CasperJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/login-with-casperjs) I didn't work apparently fill function is the one failing 
Now facebook doesn't have emai, and pass as direct children of login_form does this affect the code ? I figured it stops at this.test.assert... 
my code

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  false,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
         loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/';

casper.start(url, function() {
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.test.assertExists('form#login_form', 'form is found');
   this.fill('form#login_form', { 
        email: 'email', 
        pass:  'pass'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluateOrDie(function() {
        return /message sent/.test(document.body.innerText);
    }, 'sending message failed');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('message sent').exit();
});
```

In case no answers I got what I need working with PhantomJS only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version problem, not clear what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to phantomjs in the `batchbin/casperjs.bat` file from

```
call phantomjs "%CASPER_BIN%bootstrap.js" --casper-path="%CASPER_PATH%" --cli %ARGV%
```

to

```
call phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes "%CASPER_BIN%bootstrap.js" --casper-path="%CASPER_PATH%" --cli %ARGV%
```

This simply forces the `ignore-ssl-errors` on every call to phantomjs, which for my use case was fine. This is not a fix, just a hack.

https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/49