# 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'field.getAttribute')

Tags: javascript, authentication, casperjs

i have used code from link below to login.. it works fine with facebook ..
[How to login into a website with CasperJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/login-with-casperjs)

but it give error for login page of my site.
name of username field is LoginForm[username] and 
name of password field is LoginForm[password].

**My code.**

```
casper.start(url, function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.test.assertExists('form#login-form', 'form is found');     
   this.fill('form#login-form', { 
        LoginForm[username]: 'ascd@csc.com', 
        LoginForm[password]: '******'
    }, true);
});
```

**output**

```
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#login-form'
remote message caught: attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#login-form'
[error] [remote] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'field.getAttribute')
remote message caught: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'field.getAttribute')
Page Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'field.getAttribute')
FAIL CasperError: Unable to fill form
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "CasperError: Unable to fill form"
CasperError: Unable to fill form
```

////
HTML
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.fill('form#login-form', { 
    'LoginForm[username]': 'ascd@csc.com', 
    'LoginForm[password]': '******'
}, true);
```

Comment: sorry, fieldnames had to be quoted