# How to Login by filling the form in CasperJs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, fill, casperjs

Following is the hlml of the login form that I have

```
<div class="login_area_user">

            <form method="post" action="https://www.tradus.com/login?dest_url=https://www.tradus.com/cart/select-address" id="user-login">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form_submit">

                <h3 style="display:inline-block;">Already a Member</h3>

                <p id="login-main-center-right-descp">You can use tradus login id and password</p>

                <div class="login-row">
                    <label class="colorBlack">Email / Login*</label>
                    <input class="login-field" type="text" name="name" id="edit-namepopup">
                </div> <!-- [/login-row] -->

                <div class="login-row">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input class="login-field" type="password" id="edit-passpopup" name="pass">
                </div> <!-- [/login-row] -->

                <div class="login-row">            
                    <a class="forgotPassword" href="/forgot_password">Forgot your password?</a>
                    <!--input type="checkbox" name="remember" /><span>Remember me</span-->
                </div>

                <div class="login-row">
                    <input class="login-button" value="Login" type="submit">
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="op" value="Log in">

            </form>

        </div>
```

Am using the following code to login :

```
this.fill('form#user-login', {
        'form_submit':    1,
        'name':    'abc@gmail.com',
        'pass':   'pwd',
        'op':       'Log in'

    }, true);
```

But I dont thing its doing the thing for me.

Comment: Try using --ignore-ssl-errors=true and --web-security=false as phantomJS config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to login into a website with CasperJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/how-to-login-into-a-website-with-casperjs)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
casper.waitForSelector("form input[name='name']", function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form#user-login', {
        'input[name = name ]' : 'abc@gmail.com',
        'input[name = pass ]' : 'pwd'
    }, true);
});
```

Simply use this (see [waitForSelector docs](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector)).
Firstly, wait for the form to be loaded.
Then fill the form using the selectors.

Answer (score 10):

```
casper.waitForSelector('form', function(){
    this.fill('form', {
    'name': 'abc@gmail.com', 
    'pass': 'pwd'}, true);
});

<!-- wait until a form tag disappears -->
casper.waitWhileSelector('form', function(){
    this.echo('selector is no more!');
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else finds this.. I used some combination of these answers - my login form was also in an iframe which added some difficulty, but basically the issue I saw (cookie-based login) is that casper was going to the next step before the server could respond and set the cookie. I added some .wait() callbacks to ensure enough time to get that cookie. It may not be foolproof, but I have yet to have an issue with it

Mind you, the cookie needs to be set EVERY CRAWL

```
casper.start(config.loginUrl, function() {

console.log("Checking login status @ " + config.loginUrl);

// set a wait condition to make sure the page is loaded (particularly iframe in my case) 
this.wait(5000,function(){

    // switch to iframe (won't be necessary for most)
    this.page.switchToChildFrame('login'); 

    // fill out the form 
    this.fillSelectors("form[name='loginForm']",{
        'input#txtUsername' : config.username,
        'input#txtPassword' : config.password
    });

    // click the login button 
    console.log("Logging In...")
    this.click('input.button.login');

    // ** give my crappy dev server 5 seconds to respond
    this.wait(5000,function(){
    console.log('Starting to spider ' + dataObj.start)

    // do yo dance  
    spider(dataObj.start);
    });
```

Comment: This helped me to find the solution for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402888/casperjs-and-waitforurl-to-wait-for-next-page/40412833#40412833

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.. Follow that with:

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.evaluate(function () {
        $('form#user-login').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: this seems to be a response to a previous answer, but it's not clear which one, since the order varies unpredictably (based on how the user sorts answers, and the fluctuating values they get, and new answers coming between this and the one it refers to, etc.)