# Submitting Table Content with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to use CasperJS to populate two fields, submit a form, and print out the content of the following page. However, it does not appear that I am successfully clicking the button to go to the next page. I attempted to follow the tutorials/examples on CasperJS and answers on SO like [How to login into a website with CasperJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/login-with-casperjs). However, the difference is that I am not submitting a  but rather a table with several filled out values.

Please find my code below:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://a836-propertyportal.nyc.gov/Default.aspx', function() {});


casper.evaluate(function(block, lot) {
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_txtBlock').value = block;
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_txtLot').value = lot;
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_btnSearchBBL').click();
}, '01000', '0011');


casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo('we are this far in the code..');
    // this.echo(this.getPageContent());
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('td.contentDataElement');
    this.echo(links.length);
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        this.echo(links[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`casper.evaluate` is not a step function, but you use it on the same level as `start` and `run`. So change `casper.evaluate` to `casper.thenEvaluate`.

Also you don't have access to `document` in casper, but only inside the page context like you did with the `casper.evaluate` call.

Your fixed code uses the `casper.getElementsInfo` function to get some attributes of your desired elements. You cannot pass DOM elements from the page context to casper, they have to be of type number, string, [] or {}.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://a836-propertyportal.nyc.gov/Default.aspx');

casper.thenEvaluate(function(block, lot) {
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_txtBlock').value = block;
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_txtLot').value = lot;
    document.querySelector('#ctl00_SampleContent_ctl01_btnSearchBBL').click();
}, '01000', '0011');

casper.then(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo('we are this far in the code..');
    // this.echo(this.getPageContent());
    var links = this.getElementsInfo('td.contentDataElement');
    this.echo(links.length);
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        this.echo(JSON.stringify(links[i]));
    }
});

casper.run();
```