# node.js authenticate login form

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, authentication

I'm working with a login.aspx page where there's a login form (username/password).

Is there a way to set username and password from code so I can get other pages from the site?

Comment: you mean you want to login; save the cookie so you will be able to crawl other pages?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's what I have to do. Problem is I have no idea how to set username and password in the form from code.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something like PhantomJS or CasperJS (wrapper).

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376189/how-to-login-into-a-website-with-casperjs) for example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  false,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
         loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/';

casper.start(url, function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.test.assertExists('form#login_form', 'form is found');
   this.fill('form#login_form', { 
        email: '**<put your email here>**', 
        pass:  '**<put your password here>**'
    }, true);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
   console.log("Page Title " + document.title);
   console.log("Your name is " + document.querySelector('.headerTinymanName').textContent ); 
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thx! That's probably what I'm looking for ;)

Comment: @rickymarchiori if it works for you, please mark it as an answer :)